# Why can't I assign a value to LiveData<Boolean>?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

The Code A can work well.
I think Code B can work well too, but in fact , it failed, why ?

The error information is listed below.

*Val cannot be reassigned*

**Code A**

```
val displayCheckBox : LiveData<Boolean> = _displayCheckBox

fun switchCheckBoxShowStatus(){
   _displayCheckBox.value?.let {
       _displayCheckBox.value = !it
   }
}
```

**Code B**

```
val displayCheckBox : LiveData<Boolean> = _displayCheckBox

fun switchCheckBoxShowStatus(){
   _displayCheckBox.value?.let {
       it = !it
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it` is passed as a local variable in lambda. So basically you are trying to modify a `Val` . Which will not compile.

> inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R

As the Scoping function `let` defines it will call the block(Which is being passed as lambda) with `this` value as its argument. So its will be a method argument a `val` . So you can not reassign it.